# How can I get any statistics about "idle in transaction" connections to my PostgreSQL instance?

Tags: performance, postgresql

I want to get statistics about "idle in transaction" connections.

This statistics should be a part of performance tests results and it can reveal some bugs in the tested system.

What can I use to gather this statistics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean with "statistics" but you can see all open connections (and their transaction state) by querying the system view `pg_stat_activity`:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/monitoring-stats.html#MONITORING-STATS-VIEWS

Comment: Well, if it works, nothing prevents me from creating a simple tool which executes this query every 30 seconds and add its result to a log. That's what I mean with "statistics".

Comment: Check out pgfoundry, I think there are already scripts floating around that do that

Answer (score 1):

In *postgresql.conf* set logging to

```
log_statement = 'all'                # none, ddl, mod, all
```

and check that

```
log_line_prefix='%t:%r:%a:%u@%d:[%p]: '
```

contains %p, which is the [process ID] of the SQL.

After a reload of the database settings, in the Table *pg_stat_activity* you can read the *procpid* column of *the idle in transaction* process.

Now you can grep through the logfiles to see what SQL has been executed on the connections before they became *idle in transaction*.